# Drawing hierarchically Rectangle on WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, hierarchical

I'm trying to place `rectangles` like in the next picture

[image]

The blue arrows shows the `parent-element` from the `child`.

I got a class named `Box` with a parent propertie to a Box. 
All the created Boxes I push into an `ObservableCollection` for my bindings in the XAML code.

Here is the Box class:

```
public class Box
{
    public string Content { get; set; } //Content in the Box
    public double X { get; set; }       //For Canvas.Left propertie
    public double Y { get; set; }       //For Canvas.Right propertie
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public Box Parent { get; set; }
}
```

But now I dont get a correct way to draw the rectangles on a canvas like in the picture. I got the idea to create a grid with different column amount but I'm not shure if this is possible.

Best regards.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Do you need help with the code that's not working? Do you want to know how a grid works?

Comment: I need a start help, what is a good way to draw the rectangle with the parent like in the picture. I know how the grid works.

Comment: Is the box hierarchy fixed, or do you want to change it dynamically?

Comment: dynamically, because it should be possible to delete a child, add a child or set a new parent.

Comment: If you drop the `Parent` and instead add an `ObservableCollection<Box> Children` you can create a user control that's a grid with two rows, one on top for itself and recursive ones in the bottom row.

Comment: Don't understand so right what you mean. So remove the ´Parent´ propertie?

Comment: Building a good user control is beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow question. I recommend you read a good book (I found "WPF Control Development Unleashed" helpful) and come back when you have questions that are more limited in scope.

Comment: My question is limited in scope. I need some start help to reliaze the picture above. I'm drawing Rectangles on the Canvas. But i have problem with the hierachically drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw Rectangles in a Canvas just for layout purpose, it will be much easier by taking advantage of WPF's Panels. To use complete binding with ObservableCollection, a lot of coding is required. So the following is a simple example.

Box Class

```
public class Box
{
  public int Id { get; private set; }
  public int ParentId { get; private set; }
  public string Content { get; private set; }

  public Box(string content, int id, int parentId)
  {
    this.Id = id;
    this.ParentId = parentId;
    this.Content = content;
  }
}
```

BoxPanel Class inherited from StackPanel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

public class BoxPanel : StackPanel
{
  public int Id { get; private set; }

  private readonly Border topPanel;
  private readonly StackPanel bottomPanel;

  public BoxPanel()
  {
    topPanel = new Border();
    bottomPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

    this.Children.Add(topPanel);
    this.Children.Add(bottomPanel);
  }

  public BoxPanel(Box box)
    : this()
  {
    Id = box.Id;

    topPanel.Child = new TextBlock
    {
      Text = box.Content,
      HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
      Padding = new Thickness(14),
      Foreground = Brushes.White,
    };
    topPanel.Background = (Id % 2 == 0) ? Brushes.Gray : Brushes.DarkGray;
    topPanel.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
    topPanel.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
  }

  protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnInitialized(e);

    this.Loaded += (_, __) => AdjustBottomPanel();
    this.LayoutUpdated += (_, __) => AdjustBottomPanel();
  }

  public IReadOnlyCollection<BoxPanel> ChildrenPanel
  {
    get { return bottomPanel.Children.Cast<BoxPanel>().ToArray(); }
  }

  public void AddChildPanel(BoxPanel child)
  {
    bottomPanel.Children.Add(child);
    AdjustBottomPanel();
  }

  private void AdjustBottomPanel()
  {
    if (!ChildrenPanel.Any())
      return;

    var childWidth = Math.Max((Double.IsNaN(this.Width) ? 0 : this.Width), this.ActualWidth)
      / ChildrenPanel.Count;

    foreach (var child in ChildrenPanel)
      child.Width = childWidth;
  }
}
```

XAML of MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBoxPanel.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="240">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"/>
</Window>
```

And code behind of MainWindow

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    boxPanelRoot = new BoxPanel();
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(boxPanelRoot);

    this.Loaded += (_, __) => PopulateBoxPanel();
  }

  private readonly IList<Box> Boxes = new List<Box>
  {
    new Box("1st", 1, 0),
    new Box("2nd 1", 2, 1),
    new Box("2nd 2", 3, 1),
    new Box("3rd 1", 4, 2),
    new Box("3rd 2", 5, 2),
    new Box("3rd 3", 6, 3),
    new Box("4th 1", 7, 4),
    new Box("4th 2", 8, 5),
    new Box("4th 3", 9, 5),
    new Box("4th 4", 10, 6),
    new Box("4th 5", 11, 6),
  };

  private readonly BoxPanel boxPanelRoot;

  private void PopulateBoxPanel()
  {
    foreach (var box in Boxes)
    {
      var existingPanels = boxPanelRoot.GetDescendants() // See VisualTreeHelperExtensions.GetDescendants method of WinRT Xaml Toolkit
        .OfType<BoxPanel>()
        .ToArray();

      if (existingPanels.Any(x => x.Id == box.Id))
        continue;

      var parent = existingPanels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == box.ParentId);
      if (parent == null)
        parent = boxPanelRoot;

      parent.AddChildPanel(new BoxPanel(box));
    }
  }
}
```

[image: WpfBoxPanel screenshot]

Comment: thanks for the help. I will take a look. But a little question, waht is this "(_, __)"? I never saw this before

Comment: @R3Tech They are place holders for input parameters of lambda expression and equivalent to (sender, e) or any combination of names.  Some people use _ or __ when the parameters are not used in the method and so the names have no practical meaning but are required 
just for syntax.